# Error when I create an object in blackjack java

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a blackJack in java but i have a problem trying to create an object from a class. The code is:

Participant: This class generate a hand for player and croupier.

```
public abstract class Participant {

protected Carta[] madecartes;
protected int sumacartes;
protected boolean plantat;

public Participant(Carta[] madecartes){
    this.madecartes = madecartes;
}
public int sumaCartes(){
    for(int i = 0; i< madecartes.length;i++){
        int sumacartes = madecartes[i].getValor();
    }
    return sumacartes;
}
}
```

Player:

```
public class Jugador extends Participant {
private String nom;
public Jugador(Carta[] madecartes,String nom){
    super(madecartes);
    this.nom = nom;
    this.madecartes=madecartes;
}
public void setNom(){
    this.nom=nom;
}
public String getNom(){
    return this.nom;
}   
}
```

How can i create an object of Player(jugador) here:

```
public class BlackJack {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlackJack bj = new BlackJack();
    bj.inici();
}
public void inici(){
    Jugador j = new Jugador(madecartes,"nom");   <- error
}  
}
```

Comment: Well what is `madecartes` meant to represent? That variable doesn't exist in your `BlackJack` class. What values are you *trying* to pass to the constructor?

Comment: Its an array of Cards objects like: new Carta("3","Piques",3)

Comment: Well where do you think you're creating that array? It's certainly not in the code we've seen... (You should also say exactly what error you're receiving, rather than just that there *is* an error.)

Comment: In Participant i think

Comment: Again, not in the code you've shown (the `Participant` constructor accepts a `madecartes` parameter as well) - and even if it did, how would you expect `BlackJack.inici()` to know that you actually wanted to get that array out of a `Participant`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class Jugador has a constructor like this `Jugador(Carta[] madecartes,String nom)` so you need to pass an array of Carta in the constructor:

```
public void inici(){
    Jugador j = new Jugador(new Carta[]{myCarta1, myCarta2,etc etc}, "nom");    
}
```